# New to MVC, am I the only one getting screwed by this common scenario

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

Heres the scenario - using asp.net MVC with jquery mobile - newbie on both

Problem:  Back button sends a **GET** to a page that was created with a **POST**

Scenario:

1. Page 1 has a searchbox and submit button - clck submit does **POST** to page 2.
2. Page 2 has list of serch result links, click a search result, go to page 3
3. Click back button on page 3, and it sends a **GET** to page 2.

Tried on Safari and Firefox.  Firebug showing a GET on the back button.

Is this common?  How would you deal with this?

A) When submitting form, somehow add the textbox to the URL (sounds tricky)

B) Mark the search page action with both HTTPPost and HTTPGet?  Then save the search text in a session or somewhere?

C) Is there a better option?

Any advice appreciated!

Comment: Please rephrase your question. "Am I the only one getting screwed" isn't a useful topic, and definitely will not help anyone in the future who is searching this site for a solution to a problem. Thanks.

Comment: I'm not so sure MVC is a good choice for jQuery Mobile. I would choose Web Pages instead with Razor to keep things very simple as advanced in-code routing is just overhead in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think may have approached this the wrong way. In general, POST should be used for requests that potentially modify state (update database etc) on the server, and GET should be used for read-only operations.

In this case it is a read only action therefore a HTTP Get is the correct http verb to use. Assuming you are using Razor your form action would look like

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Get))
//generates an url like /search?q=searchterm
```

Comment: Now that I see it, it makes sense.  In the classic asp.net world I never had to think about it.  I just assumed that links to places did GET, and forms did post.  But in MVC, you have to have to wear a different hat. Thanks for the answer, i spend a few hours on this.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want page 1 and page 2 to have the same url and essentially 'post-back' to the first page, such that if you go backwards you get back to the first original non-posted page.

You can achieve this by using the [HttpPost] and [HttpGet] attributes

In your Controller you can have this

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Search()
{
   //action result get code
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search()
{
   //your result post code here
}
```